# Getting Liquibase to run an SQL script on start up with SpringBoot Kotlin

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, kotlin, liquibase

I'm having trouble getting liquibase to execute my sql script in my SpringBoot Kotlin appllication.

Here is my build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
}

group = "com.johncooper"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs("src/main")
}

sourceSets.test {
    java.srcDirs("src/test", "src/cucumber/kotlin", "src/cucumber")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.json:json:20211205")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.6.3")
    implementation("org.mariadb:r2dbc-mariadb")

    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.3")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.3")

    implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.3")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.16.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.16.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:mariadb:1.16.3")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:r2dbc:1.16.0")
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.11.0")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:6.11.0")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.11.0")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks {
    test {
        filter {
            excludeTestsMatching("**.RunBDDTests")
        }
    }
}

task<Test>("acceptanceTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("**.RunBDDTests")
    }
}
```

And here is my application.properties -

```
server.port=9000

spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:mariadb://0.0.0.0:3306/mydb
spring.r2dbc.username=testuser
spring.r2dbc.password=mypwd
spring.r2dbc.initialization-mode= always

spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:mariadb://0.0.0.0:3306/mydb
spring.liquibase.user=testuser
spring.liquibase.password=mypwd
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.enabled=true

logging.level.org.springframework.data.r2dbc=INFO
debug=false
logging.level.com.johncooper=INFO
```

Here is my db.changelog-master.xml located in src/main/resources/db/changelog/ -

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <include file="data.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And here is the script I want execute data.sql -

```
# liquibase formatted sql
# changeset mydb:data

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pets;

CREATE TABLE pets (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   description VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   breed VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   price VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO pets (name, description, breed, type, price) VALUES
 ('Nemo', 'fish', 'piranah', 'a fricking fich', '$100')

# rollback DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydb.pets
```

There are no errors on running the application `./gradlew bootRun` through Intellij. The script simply doesn't get run. Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

Update - here is a link to the github repo with my code: https://github.com/johnnyalpha8/Pet-Shop

Comment: I cannot reproduce your set up right now, so this is just a guess. But are you sure it is allowed to `include` a sql-file in the `databaseChangeLog` directly? When I worked with liquibase, we only had `changeSet` elements as direct children. These were included with an `include` normally. Inside a `changeSet` we might use raw sql statements, even though I'd recommend using the abilities of liquibase instead, to profit from the rollback support.

Comment: Thanks Endzeit, actually it is indeed allowed to include the sql file in the databaseChangeLog like this - <include file="data.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>.

Comment: I've got it to work with sql scripts by removing the version from  implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.3") like this  implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client"). Presumably, Spring then handles the dependency!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running your setup with debug logs enabled, I've noticed that auto-configuration for Liquibase did not work, as some criteria was not met.

```
LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseConfiguration:
   Did not match:
      - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback' (OnClassCondition)
```

The class `org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback` is provided as part of the `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc`.
With the following adjustments to your `build.gradle.kts`, your `.sql`-file is picked up by Liquibase.

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // - provides the missing class for auto-configuration 
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")

    ...

    // - this dependency seems to be unnecessary
    // implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.3")
    // - you provided an outdated version
    // - a version must not be provided as it is managed by Spring Boot 
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")

    ...
```

---

However, your `.sql` script contains a syntax error. I am not familiar with Liquibase based on `.sql`-files, but I've got it to run using the `.xml`-file syntax for Liquibase.

**db.changelog-master.xml**

```xml
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <include file="db.changelog-0001.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**db.changelog-0001.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.3.xsd">
    <changeSet id="1" author="jalpha">
        <createTable tableName="pets">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(250)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="description" type="varchar(250)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="breed" type="varchar(250)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="type" type="varchar(250)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="price" type="varchar(250)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <insert tableName="pets">
            <column name="name" value="Nemo"/>
            <column name="description" value="fish"/>
            <column name="breed" value="piranah"/>
            <column name="type" value="a fricking fich"/>
            <column name="price" value="$100"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

---

Thank you for providing an example repository, this helped reproducing the error immensely.